# How do you get notifications from a WebHook Connector posting?

Tags: notifications, webhooks, office365connectors

I am building an AWS Lambda function that posts CloudWatch event notifications to our MS Teams group using the Incoming WebHook connector.  Everything seems to work great, the messages are formatted nicely, images work fine, sections are good, etc.  However, there I can't seem to generate any notifications (banner, email, etc.) when the message get's posted.  The UI updates correctly (**bold**ed channel name, "New Messages" widget, etc.) but that's it.

I need to be actively notified when some things happen.  For example, when someone does something unusual in AWS I want to know about it immediately.  I don't want to have to look at the GUI to see if anything happened.  This is a basic functionality that is in almost every other chat application.  How do I turn it on for messages coming from the WebHook Connector?

Comment: I tried "following" a channel specifically for some of our webhooks, but the Windows desktop application for Teams didn't display any notifications when that channel received an incoming webhook.

Comment: See this page which requests this feature https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/17022934-notification-for-connectors